# Filtering a list with indexes MIT-scheme

Tags: scheme, filtering, higher-order-functions, mit-scheme

Is there a good way to filter a list using each element and its index in scheme? This is how I'm doing it now, but it seems overly complex

```
(map cdr
     (filter (lambda (index-and-element)
               (filter-proc (car index-and-element) 
                            (cdr index-and-element)))
             (map cons (iota (length l))
                       l)))
```

Comment: looks perfectly fine to me. :) except, perhaps you meant `map cdr`.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I guess I'm used to bigger languages, because usually when I write something like this it means I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: could you give an example of what you mean, in some "bigger" language? (also, personally I like very short var names whenever possible, so instead of `index-and-element` I'd just use `ie` -- they are unimportant, it's just some wiring, so make them as invisible as possible :) )

Comment: That does simplify it, thanks! As for examples, here is how I would do it in python and javascript.

`[x for i, x in enumerate(l) if filter_proc(i, x)]`

`l.filter(filterProc)`

Comment: ah, list comprehensions. Haskell has them too. Racket too, I think. Maybe there's some SRFI for Scheme, too. (that's "Scheme request for implementation", common extensions for Scheme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfectly fine to me. Except, perhaps you meant `map cdr`...

Personally I like very short variable names whenever possible, so instead of `index-and-element` I'd just use `ie` -- they are unimportant, it's just some wiring, so make them as invisible as possible.

Another possibility is to use `(map list ...)` initially, not `(map cons ...)`, and then inside the `lambda` to use `(apply filter-proc ie)`. this way `filter-proc` is called with two arguments, so it can be defined `(define (filter-proc idx elt) ...)`.

And after all that, since it is indeed complex and error-prone to type all this anew each time, we'd just define a higher-order function for this so it is easier to use, like

```
(define (indexed-filter ipred lst)
   (filter (lambda (ie)
               (apply ipred ie))
           (map list (iota (length lst))
                     lst)))

;; (define (ipred idx elt) ....)  ; returns Bool
```

and use *it* whenever the need arises.

I've intentionally left  out the `(map cadr ...)` post-processing step, since you could sometimes want to get the indices of the matching elements instead of the elements themselves. So *that* would be part of the calling "protocol" so to speak -- whether you're interested in indices, elements, or both, you'd just tweak the call to this general procedure.

Comment: I think it still needs a `(map cadr ...` around the filter to turn the lists back into elements.